# Combinde two lists of strings without getting tuples

Tags: python, list, join, merge, zip

I have two lists:

```
country_name = ['South Africa', 'India', 'United States']
country_code = ['ZA', 'IN', 'US']
```

My goal is to zip and join them, so that I get the following list:

```
countries = ['South Africa ZA', 'India IN', 'United States US']
```

Comment: `countries = [" ".join(tpl) for tpl in zip(country_name, country_code)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `zip` with so-called list-comprehension.

```
country_name = ['South Africa', 'India', 'United States']
country_code = ['ZA', 'IN', 'US']
countries = [' '.join(x) for x in zip(country_name, country_code)]
print(countries)
```

Output:

```
['South Africa ZA', 'India IN', 'United States US']
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to be the most elegant solution. Since computation time is not so important for me, this is the way to go :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
countries = []

for i in range(0,len(country_name)):
    countries.append(country_name[i]+" "+country_code[i])
```

As simple as this

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to be the fastes solution in terms of computation time

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension

```
country_name = ['South Africa', 'India', 'United States']
country_code = ['ZA', 'IN', 'US']
countries = [name + ' ' + code for name, code in zip(country_name, country_code)]
```

Output

```
>>> print(countries)
['South Africa ZA', 'India IN', 'United States US']
```